# Gulp.js - watch and compile swig.js template files on change

Tags: javascript, node.js, task, swig-template, gulp

I'm stucked with the problem of watching my **Swig.js** html templates and compiling them on every change, I use **Gulp.js** task runner for that purpose. Here is my **gulpfile.js**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var myth = require('gulp-myth');
var swig = require('gulp-swig');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

gulp.task('styles', function () {
  gulp.src('./myth/*.css')
    .pipe(myth())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/css'));
});

gulp.task('templates', function () {
  gulp.src('./views/*.html')
    .pipe(swig({ load_json: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./client'));
});

gulp.task('server', function () {
  gulp.run('styles');
  gulp.run('templates');

  gulp.src('./server.js').pipe(nodemon());

  gulp.watch('./myth/*.css', function () {
     gulp.run('styles');
  });

  gulp.watch('./views/*.html', function () {
     gulp.run('templates');
  }); 
});
```

**Myth** task *styles* runs fine - on every change of `myth/*.css` I got updated file in `client/css/`..

But task called *templates* gives result only once.. When I change `views/index.html` file in `client/index.html` stays the same. In my console I see that *templates* task was ran but results still the same..

```
MacBook-Pro-Dmitri:slick-grid dmitri$ gulp server
[gulp] Using file /Users/dmitri/github/slick-grid/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Working directory changed to /Users/dmitri/github/slick-grid
[gulp] Running 'server'...
[gulp] Running 'styles'...
[gulp] Finished 'styles' in 4.02 ms
[gulp] Running 'templates'...
[gulp] Finished 'templates' in 1.29 ms
[gulp] Running 'watch'...
[gulp] Finished 'watch' in 7.23 ms
[gulp] Finished 'server' in 16 ms
>> Strata web server version 0.20.1 running on node 0.10.21
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000, CTRL+C to stop

// Here I changed my views/index.html, task is ran as you see (but dest file won't be updated):

[gulp] Running 'templates'...
[gulp] Finished 'templates' in 668 μs 
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2014:15:43:20 +-200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 511
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2014:15:43:20 +-200] "GET /css/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1419
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2014:15:43:20 +-200] "GET /css/app.css HTTP/1.1" 200 865
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2014:15:43:20 +-200] "GET /fonts/likeastore-icon-font.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 15052
```

Maybe I'm missing some cache options or similar?!

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/colynb/gulp-swig/pull/1). Swig caches templates by default and as of yet, there isn't a way to turn off caching with `gulp-swig`.

Comment: @robertklep thanks! hope this guys will merge soon!

Answer (score 12):

Gulp-Swig has been updated to allow disabling of the cache option - as well as setting other swig defaults, as shown below.

```
gulp.task('templates', function() {
  gulp.src('./views/*.html')
    .pipe(swig({
      load_json: true,
      defaults: {
        cache: false,
        locals: {
          site_name: "My Blog"
        }
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./client'));
});
```

Comment: In which version of gulp-swig was this introduced?

Comment: Looks like it was v0.1.0 https://github.com/colynb/gulp-swig/commit/bc677e8d7ae30a90cba757fd7098a9332ef17404

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Just wanted to check I was running the right version. Thanks for gulp-swig btw.

Comment: This does unfortunately not work for me. I have the same setup, but while `watch` is running it doesn't update my files even though `{ defaults: { cache: false } }` is set. Any tips what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

*Edit: **Configuration may no longer work** as per Mike Aski's comment*

I had a similar issue where [gulp-livereload](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-livereload) and [tiny-lr](https://www.npmjs.org/package/tiny-lr) was refreshing the page but not showing an updated template.  I'm not using [gulp-swig](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-swig) (although that looks like a good solution), so I just changed **app.js**:

```
swig = require("swig");

swig.setDefaults({
  cache: false
});

app = express();

app.set('view cache', false);
```